# serial port over tcp without terminal server

Tags: serial-port

Using pandboard, i would like to forward the ttyO2 port where first login comes up and gives a bash.

Without using a terminal server (intermediate PC or serial-server) as pandaboard support eth0 how can i leverage this eth0 to share the ttyO2 and access the bash prompt as well as kernel logs (runtime).

Have tried socat, netcat, ser2net ser2sock etc... but they don't give me access the bash prompt which is available on ttyO2 to interact but a separate pipe is create and both host and device can chat but no commands can be issued.

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to forward the ttyO2 port where first login comes up and gives a bash.

That is not possible.
The output of a **device** cannot be redirected somewhere else from within the kernel.
There are external hardware solutions, such as serial-to-Ethernet converters (aka modem replacement devices).

However the logical **console** does not have be be assigned (solely) to the serial port.
The console can also be assigned to the "**netconsole**", which will output most of the kernel boot messages.  Once the kernel has booted, you can telnet or ssh into the system.

The [Linux kernel documenation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt) describes its features and use.
The netconsole and Ethernet driver(s) have to be built-in to the kernel (i.e. cannot be loadable modules), so you may have to reconfigure and build a kernel for your Pandaboard.
The kernel command line would have to be edited to activate the netconsole:

```
 netconsole=[src-port]@[src-ip]/[<dev>],[tgt-port]@<tgt-ip>/[tgt-macaddr]

   where
        src-port      source for UDP packets (defaults to 6665)
        src-ip        source IP to use (interface address)
        dev           network interface (eth0)
        tgt-port      port for logging agent (6666)
        tgt-ip        IP address for logging agent
        tgt-macaddr   ethernet MAC address for logging agent (broadcast)
```